# Recoding multiple variables to "Other"

Tags: r, recode, data-wrangling

I have done some recoding to my dataframe to reflect groups that I wish to run analyses on, but need to code everything else as "Other". See below:

```
DF:
  Var1
   BIO
   CHEM
   Arts
   BIO
   Zoo
   Edu
   Math
   BIO
```

What I want is:

DF:
Var1
BIO
CHEM
Other
BIO
Other
Other
Other
BIO
PSY

I have tried this code:

```
DF[ Var1 ==c(!"BIO", "CHEM", "PSY")] <- "Other"
```

But this does not work. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an adapted version of your code. It works for character strings.

```
DF$Var1[!DF$Var1 %in% c("BIO", "CHEM", "PSY")] <- "Other"
```

For factors you may use:

```
fct_other(DF$Var1, keep = c("BIO", "CHEM", "PSY"), other_level = "Other")
```